# How Does a P3-Configured AVCaptureDevice fit its 10-bit Color Data into the 8-bit 32BGRA Pixel Format?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, color-space, avcapturedevice

Title says it all basically. When you configure an `AVCaptureDevice` to return pixels with a P3 colorspace (which Apple says is 10-bit, and recommends using a 16-bit pixel format to contain), your only pixel format output choices are still only `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` and the two planars.

So I don't understand how you're being returned deeper color data, that needs 10-bits with the same 8-bit format??

And they explicitly state that it is possible to take P3 video (though discouraged for playback compatibility reasons).

Maybe only when you use a `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`, and not if you're receiving the raw pixel buffers? That's all I can think.